# What does $R^+$ mean?

Tags: notation

I'm not sure if it's statistics related but I came over this in my stats related computing assignment.

Does $R^+$ (looks like R to the power of plus) mean all positive real numbers? Does it include 0?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Let+R%2B%22

Comment: To clarify (though the explicit answer can be found among in many of the links I get from my linked search above); usually it means positive reals rather than non-negative reals.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. You should ask your course instructor to clarify the definition.

I met the two definitions from different sources. One is non-negative real numbers. Another is positive numbers.